# Copy one list to another by looping through xslt

Tags: xslt

Sample list is below. The records for movie tag will increase in real time. I want to copy all the movie tags to <movies_Copy> <movie_copy> </movie_copy></movies_Copy> when ever new movie gets added using xslt request.

```
<movies>
    <movie>
        <movieId>1</movieId>
        <moviename>Jungle Book-I</moviename>            
    </movie>
    <movie>
         <movieId>2</movieId>
         <moviename>Jungle Book-II</moviename> 
    </movie>
</movies>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the records for movie tag will increase in real time"? Are you dealing with a file? With a stream you are getting from some service? How is your XSLT transformation executed?

Comment: What did you try so far?